# Android Navigation Drawer Appears on top of mRenderSurfaceView on API<=4.0.3

Tags: android, layout, z-index, andengine, navigation-drawer

I am trying to combine Andengine's mRenderSurfaceView with a standard android application.
I created a standard Android project with navigation drawer, and succesfully plugged in the mRenderSurfaceView.

Problem: on Android 2.3 and on android 4.0.3, the navigation drawer appears below the mRenderSurfaceView only when it is being pulled out. When the drawer full opens it comes back to front.

Any idea how to make the drawer always on top, even when it is being pulled out?

XML Layout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.epollomes.caniconnect.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.epollomes.caniconnect.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

OnCreate where the ,RenderSurfaceView is added to the FrameLayout

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ActivityUtils.requestFullscreen(this);
    //
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //
    //
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = BaseGameActivity.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams();

    // new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    // LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
    frameLayout.addView(mRenderSurfaceView);
    frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    // this.setContentView(this.mRenderSurfaceView,
    // BaseGameActivity.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
    //
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        mRenderSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
    }
    //
    //
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

Please let me know if any additional info is needed. 
Thanks

Comment: If you directly declare AndEngine RenderSurfaceView in xml instead of in java code, does it make any difference?

Comment: Same thing with xml, what is weird is that on API>=4.1 it works just fine.

Comment: I did a workaround so that I stop being blocked which is to set a touch listener on the drawer on the older API <4.1 and inside the event manually move to front the drawer, because a single call did not fix it:
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerListView.bringToFront();
         mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerListView.getParent().requestLayout();
         mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.invalidate();
    }
   });

It isn't a clean workaround, at it keeps calling the above methods while the finger is on the drawer.